# Nyquist criterion - undefined variable in algorithm

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, nyquist

I write an algorithm that checks the stability of the closed system of the Nyquist criterion (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_stability_criterion)

```
    function answear=stability(re,im)
%% Function check stability of system
%re is real part of transmitation
%im is imagine part of transmitation

%% Check number of vectors elements
re(end +1:5) = 0;
im(end +1:5) = 0;

if( length(re) > length(im))
    root = length(re);
else
    root = length(im);
end

for w=1:root
    tran(w) = re(1) + re(2)*w.^1 + re(3)*w.^2 + re(4)*w.^3 + re(5)*w.^4 +1i*(...
     im(1) + im(2)*w.^1 + im(3)*w.^2 + im(4)*w.^3 +im(5)*w.^4);
end

%% Algorithm
switch root
    case 0
        exist('Write nonzero numbers', 'var')
    case 1
    for w=1:length(w)
        if( real(tran(w)) > 0 && imag(tran(w)) > 0) 
            answear=1;
        else
            answear=0;
        end
    end
    case 2
    for w=1:length(w)
        if( real(tran(w)) > 0 && imag(tran(w)) > 0) 
            if( real(tran(w)) < 0 && imag(tran(w)) > 0) 
                answear=1;
            else
                answear=0;
            end
        end
        end
    case 3
    for w=1:length(w)
        if( real(tran(w)) > 0 && imag(tran(w)) > 0) 
            if( real(tran(w)) < 0 && imag(tran(w)) > 0) 
                if( real(tran(w)) < 0 && imag(tran(w)) < 0) 
                    answear=1;
                else
                    answear=0;
                end
            end
        end
    end
    case 4
    for w=1:length(w)
         if( real(tran(w)) > 0 && imag(tran(w)) > 0) 
            if( real(tran(w)) < 0 && imag(tran(w)) > 0) 
                if( real(tran(w)) < 0 && imag(tran(w)) < 0)
                    if( real(tran(w)) > 0 && imag(tran(w)) < 0) 
                        answear=1;
                    else
                        answear=0;
                    end
                end
            end
         end
    end
end

%% Answear
if answear==1
    disp('System unstable')
else
    disp('System stable')
end
plot(real(tran),imag(tran)) 
grid on

end
```

Function returns

> Undefined function or variable "answear".
>
> Error in stability (line 87) if answear==1

So the algorithm is badly written?

Answer (score 2):

Your code could use a lot of cleanup:

1. Instead of an if-statement such as this one:

   ```
   if( real(tran(w)) > 0 && imag(tran(w)) > 0) 
       answear=1;
   else
       answear=0;
   end
   ```

   you could write a boolean assignment:

   ```
   answear = real(tran(w)) > 0 & imag(tran(w)) > 0);
   ```
2. Why do you have three (almost) identical nested if-statements at all?

   ```
   if( real(tran(w)) > 0 && imag(tran(w)) > 0) 
       if( real(tran(w)) < 0 && imag(tran(w)) > 0) 
           if( real(tran(w)) < 0 && imag(tran(w)) < 0)
   ```

   First of all, you could replace everything with one if-statement. But what are you actually testing with this? It seems that those nested if statements are never executed. For instance, `real(tran(w))` cannot be both positive and negative at the same time (unless  it is a vector you are working on, in which case you shouldn't be using the operator `&&`).

   Also, this is probably your code triggers the error regarding variable `answear`. Accessing it is impossible since it hasn't been assigned a value (none of the if-statements have been executed).
3. What is `tran`, and what is `w`? Are they global variables? If they are, pass them as input parameters. Your function is probably poorly designed if it relies on external states and variables.

I haven't actually run your code, but these suggestions should make it easier for you to debug it.

**P.S**: 
Please fix the annoying spelling error (it is "answer" and not "answear") :)

Comment: 2.To check the stability of the Nyquist criterion - graph must go through as many quadrants of the coordinate system, which is a row transfer function (equation). For example, if the expression is a three-degree, graph passes successively through I, II, III quarter system. That's why I try to check in a loop each character real and imaginary parts of the expression. Tran is transmittance, w is pulsation(frequency).

Comment: @Kulis Again, read my comment carefully: the expressions `tran(w) > 0` and `tran(w) < 0` cannot be true simultaneously.